# mybatis+redis+spring=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, spring, redis, mybatis

everything works without cache.
Then I want to cache mybatis with redis, so I did this:

1. Add `<cache/>` right below `<mapper>` in mapper.xml
2. Add `<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:conf/spring/mybatis-config.xml" />` in jdbc.xml `sqlSessionFactory` bean configuration.

Then I run `TestClass`, I see that both select statements are executed in mysql general.log, I think this means the cache does not work.

So I tried other solutions that I found online:
solution1 I tried: using `<cache type="org.mybatis.caches.redis.RedisCache" />`
solution2 I tried: define my own `MyCache` (using redis of course), define my own serialization class, and add `@CacheNamespace(implementation=(com.cmcc.wensi.service.MyCache.class))` to DAO interface `ConfigMapper`. Now I get:

```
[2016-11-18 14:52:04,100] [main] (AbstractBeanFactory.java:1490) WARN  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'msgMapper' defined in file [D:\...\MsgMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [conf/spring/jdbc.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [D:\...\ConfigMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.cache.CacheException: Could not instantiate cache implementation (class com.cmcc.wensi.service.RedisCache). Cause: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

TestClass:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:conf/applicationContext.xml" })  
@Transactional(readOnly=false)  
public class TestConfigService {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigServiceImpl configService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("output:" + configService.get(ConfigKeyEnum.DEFAULT_PRIZE));
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("output:" + configService.get(ConfigKeyEnum.DEFAULT_PRIZE));
    }
}
```

mybatis-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
  <settings>
      <setting name="cacheEnabled" value="true"/>
  </settings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: iBatis 3 docs claim that the cache is enabled by default so you don't need to do it explicitely. Are you sure there is a `com.cmcc.wensi.service.RedisCache` on a classpath? Is this a full stacktrace - because the InvocationTargetException should also point to the reason of that. Try to increase logging level to DEBUG and see then.

Comment: @RafalG. Now log4j is at debug level, but still this is the whole WARN. the others are DEBUG. But I noticed quite many:Find JAR URL: file:/D:/.../model/Activity.class
[2016-11-18 15:35:41,250] [main] (DefaultVFS.java:217) DEBUG org.apache.ibatis.io.ResolverUtil - Not a JAR: file:/D:/.../model/Activity.class
[2016-11-18 15:35:41,251] [main] (DefaultVFS.java:94) DEBUG org.apache.ibatis.io.ResolverUtil - Reader entry: ����

Comment: @RafalG. moreover, if ibatis has cache turned on, why I see mysql general log has 2 SELECT ... printed

Comment: Yeah, what do I know: http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html

Comment: Instead of a single line, post the whole stack trace. Don't post additions as comments, edit your question instead and provide the additional information. In comments code is unreadable.

Comment: @M.Deinum could use a chat room for the output. Too large, one has to scroll screen

Comment: @M.Deinum I finally found the problem. it is this exception "targetInvokeError" means something wrong with the called method (using reflection), so I debug the program, and found there was a spring NULL bean and it causes NPE. Thanks :)

Comment: @RafalG got the point. so only add <cache "path to rediscache class"/>